# Summation with exclusion or skipped step

Tags: summation, notation

For example, when $i=0$ and $j=0$, the term $\displaystyle\frac{1}{i+j}$ is invalid. How do I indicate in the equation that $i$ and $j$ cannot be $0$ at the same time and this case should be excluded from the summation?
$$\sum_{i=-5}^{5} \sum_{j=-5}^{5}{\frac{1}{i+j}}$$

Answer (score 2):

The [Iverson bracket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) does exactly what you've asked for:
$$\sum_{i=-5}^5 \sum_{j=-5}^5 \frac{[i+j \not=0]}{i+j}$$
For summation, the convention is that if the Iverson bracket returns false, the term is omitted.

But if you don't like the Iverson bracket, here are a few other ways to exclude the cases with a zero denominator:

$$\sum_{i=-5}^5 \sum_{j\in\{-5,\dots,5\}\setminus\{-i\}}\frac{1}{i+j}$$

$$\sum_{\substack{-5 \le i, j \le 5:\\ i+j \not= 0}}\frac{1}{i+j}$$

$$\sum_{\substack{(i,j)\in \{-5,\dots,5\} \times \{-5,\dots,5\}:\\ i+j \not= 0}}\frac{1}{i+j}$$

$$\sum_{\substack{(i,j)\in \{-5,\dots,5\}^2:\\ i+j \not= 0}}\frac{1}{i+j}$$

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC No, the convention is to omit the term when $[]=0$.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket

Comment: I did a largish rewrite, fronting the property of the bracket. Hope you don't mind, feel free to revert if you prefer the previous version.

Answer (score 2):

First, why haven't you mentioned the case where $i=1,j=-1$?

But glossing over that, I could swear I've seen people put a prime symbol on the sigma, $\sum'$, to indicate "please skip index values that make the term nonsensical", but I can neither find a reference for this, or figure out exactly how you'd do it with your double summation symbols. Maybe

$$\sum_{i,j=-5}^{5}{\vphantom{\sum}}' \frac{1}{i+j}$$

or

$$\sum_{-5 \le i,j \le 5}{\vphantom{\sum}}' \frac{1}{i+j}$$

Regardless, you should still explain what you mean by the primed sigma, as I don't think it's a standard notation.

Further googling uncovers that the "primed sigma" notation is used when summing over a lattice, when studying doubly periodic complex functions a la Weierstrass, and means "skip the point $(0,0)$" when used there. So not the exact same thing, but possibly close enough to validate borrowing it for your purpose.

Comment: I've seen the primed summation as well in physics. (Google Books has a bunch of hits for "primed sigma notation excluded case".)

Comment: So maybe it is a good notation, so long as one realizes they have to make clear what cases they are excluding.

Answer (score 0):

Another common notation is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=-5}^5\sum_{\color{blue}{{j=-5}\atop{j\ne -i}}}^{5}\frac{1}{i+j}
\end{align*}